# SwiftUI Picker not really selecting a value in memory on view load (populated with firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, picker

I have a simple picker that does successfully populate with values from my firebase container.  It also seems to select the first option as the default.  When I actually test that tho, when the view is loaded, no value is actually selected.  It isn't until I switch the picker to another value that Swift picks up the value.  Am I missing something here?  Why isn't the default value getting picked up right away when the view loads?

I also get this message in the console:

> Picker: the selection "" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results.

```
TextField(text: $team){
     Text("\(teamSelection)").foregroundColor(.gray)
}.disabled(true)
 .padding(10)
    Picker("teamName", selection: $teamSelection) {
    ForEach(self.teamModel.list) { i in
      Text(i.teamName).tag(i.teamName)
     }
    }.onAppear(perform: {teamModel.fetchData()})
```

Comment: do you update  `teamSelection` when your data is fetched  ?